# (PHP) Simple HTML DOM parser: HTML symbols

Tags: php, json, html-parsing, special-characters, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get usernames from [this website](http://www.foody.vn/ha-noi/sumo-bbq-hoang-quoc-viet) and this is what I've done:

```
$div = $html->find('div[class=micro-home-recent-review review-item]');
for ($i=0; $i<count($div); $i++){  
     $username = $div[$i]->find('div[class=tooltip-fullname]', 0)->find('b', 0)->plaintext;
     // I've tried using iconv but apparently it doesn't work
     $username = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($username), "UTF-8", $username); 
     $query = "INSERT INTO users ('name') VALUES ($username)";
     $pdo->query($query);
}
```

Then the newly inserted records in my database are:

[image: database records]

As you can see, most of the names are recorded with HTML symbols, which can be displayed normally on browsers, but get messed up when shown as JSON. The same problem happens when I tried to get reviews, and below is the sample JSON of a review:

[image]

I need the JSON to show data in my Android app, therefore this problem needs to be solved or the data won't be displayed properly. What could be a possible solution for this? I really need your help and suggestions.

Comment: Is this your site (ie you hold the server) or are you scraping an external one? If you don't own the site, have you informed the owner of your activity?

Comment: Although not likely related to your problem, this use of `mb_detect_encoding` is highly suspicious. What are the possible encodings that you are detecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function.

Comment: This is correct **if** the entities are present in the source data (possible, but requires proof).

Answer (score 1):

use `htmlentities_decode()` that will solve your problem.